# Maintain other styles after rotating text in flex box

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, ag-grid-react

I am working with Table(Ag-grid). Style of headers is conferrable (can be changed via props) i.e
height/width and Text-aligment can be changed.
Since I don't have access to header height in Each Header cell so I am using flex box in header cells to maintain text alignment(vertical/horizontal) properly.

Now I got a new change request to have one more style to make text(HeaderName) vertical So the user can rotate text for those Header where width is not sufficient. like that [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjmGz.png).
For that I have done changes in HeaderCellRenderer

My Issue Is If I rotate the Text my vertical alignment (top/center/bottom) and horizontal alignment(left/center/right) is not as expected by client. All alignment should work as same as when the text is not rotated.

Please assist me to do so.

This is a plunker link I have attached just to show you how my Header cell is(Its dummy) , and the issue I am facing.
After applying rotate then text align (top/bottom/left/right) system should behave same as with non-rotate.

```js
// Add your code here
function hori(value) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("outer");
  x[0].style.textAlign = value;
 // alert('changed');

  
}
function vertical(value) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("inner");
  x[0].style.alignSelf = value;
 // alert('changed');

  
}
function rotate() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("inner");
  x[0].style.transform = 'rotate(-90deg)';
}
function rotate() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("inner");
  x[0].style.transform = 'rotate(-90deg)';
}
function Notrotate() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("inner");
  x[0].style.transform = 'none';
}
```

```css
/* Add your styles here */
.outer {
    text-align : center;
    display : flex;
    height : 100px;
    width : 200px;
    background-color : yellow;
    color: red;
    overflow : hidden;
    border : 1px solid black;
    
    
}
.inner {
    align-self : center;
    width : 100%;
   
    
    
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    
<button onclick="rotate()">rotate</button>
<button onclick="Notrotate()">Not rotate</button>
<button onclick="vertical('flex-start')">v-top</button>
<button onclick="vertical('center')">v-center</button>
<button onclick="vertical('flex-end')">v-end</button>
<button onclick="hori('left')">left</button>
<button onclick="hori('center')">center</button>
<button onclick="hori('right')">right</button>
<hr/>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
      text
    </div>
        
        
    </div>
    
  
</body>
</html>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/epE0bXvqePvpS2zL?preview

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a "transform-origin" and remove the "width: 100%" then you have to move your inner container with flex properties (justify-content)

```js
// Add your code here
function hori(value) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("outer");
  x[0].style.justifyContent = value;
 // alert('changed');

  
}
function vertical(value) {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("inner");
  x[0].style.alignSelf = value;
 // alert('changed');

  
}
function rotate() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("inner");
  x[0].style.transform = 'rotate(-90deg)';
}
function rotate() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("inner");
  x[0].style.transform = 'rotate(-90deg)';
}
function Notrotate() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("inner");
  x[0].style.transform = 'none';
}
```

```css
    .outer {
        text-align : center;
        display : flex;
        height : 100px;
        width : 200px;
        background-color : yellow;
        color: red;
        border : 1px solid black;
    }
    .inner {
        align-self : center;
        transform-origin: center;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    
<button onclick="rotate()">rotate</button>
<button onclick="Notrotate()">Not rotate</button>
<button onclick="vertical('flex-start')">v-top</button>
<button onclick="vertical('center')">v-center</button>
<button onclick="vertical('flex-end')">v-end</button>
<button onclick="hori('flex-start')">left</button>
<button onclick="hori('center')">center</button>
<button onclick="hori('flex-end')">right</button>
<hr/>
    <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
      text
    </div>
        
        
    </div>
    
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, I can't use justify-content because most of the time we uses center alignment(horizontally) . and It should place in center if box(cell-width) is bigger than text and It should align left automatically, if text(header Name) is bigger than box. With text-align property it is working fine,

Comment: Other more important acpect here is after rotating text and moving v-top and v-bottom . Some text is getting truncated at top and bottom side. How Can I prevent this text truncation. here user can adject height and width and can also edit the header Name(text) , Please suggest How to apply dynamic margin on top and bottom to prevent text truncation.